# Split an array into multiple arrays in random order - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, random, slice

I am trying to split an array of names into multiple arrays in random order each time it is run. I know how to split them with:

```
 name_array = ["bob","john","rob","nate","nelly","michael"]
 array = name_array.each_slice(2).to_a
 => [["bob", "john"], ["rob", "nate"], ["nelly", "michael"]]
```

But, what if I want it to spit them out in random order each time?

Comment: Your example doesn't require Array#slice at all. Array#sample is the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before do the same thing, shuffle the array. ([`Array#shuffle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shuffle))

```
name_array.shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a
# => [["nelly", "nate"], ["rob", "bob"], ["michael", "john"]]
```

or, shuffle afterward according to your need:

```
name_array.each_slice(2).to_a.shuffle
# => [["nelly", "michael"], ["rob", "nate"], ["bob", "john"]]
```

Comment: Oh I see. Didn't know about the shuffle method. Thank you for the quick response. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

### Random Sampling

If you know the size of the original array, then:

```
name_array.sample 6
```

[Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sample) shortens your method chain over the use of [Array#shuffle](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-shuffle). If you don't want to hard-code the size of the sample, you can introspect the array for its size at run-time. For example:

```
name_array.sample(name_array.size)
```

### Permutation

If you don't need to insist that a given name appears only once in your result set, then you might also consider [Array#permutation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-permutation):

```
name_array.permutation(2).to_a.sample(name_array.size)
```

The results will vary, but here's a pretty-printed sample of the results you might expect from this approach:

```
[["michael", "rob"],
 ["bob", "nelly"],
 ["rob", "bob"],
 ["michael", "nelly"],
 ["john", "michael"],
 ["john", "rob"]]
```

Comment: Use `combination` rather than `permutation` if you wish to avoid the possibility of both `["bob", "rob"]` and `["rob", "bob"]` appearing in the sample.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that's a valid point, but in this specific case it doesn't buy you much over shuffling or sampling. The point of highlighting permutation was that it gives a different *kind* of result for this input set. There are lots of other array methods, including #combination and #each_cons, that yield different sorts of results with different constraints. Array and Enumerable are full of useful tidbits. YMMV.

Comment: Here, the only differences between `combination` and `permutation` are that the former keeps the ordering in `name_array` in the sample pairs, and prevents the sort of duplicates I mentioned above.  Both permit the sample to contain `["bob", "john"]` and `["bob", "rob"]`, though `permutation` might instead or in addition have `["john", "bob"]` or `["rob", "bob"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Shuffle the array first, then slice:

```
["bob","john","rob","nate","nelly","michael"].shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [["nelly", "nate"], ["rob", "michael"], ["john", "bob"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array = name_array.each_slice(2).to_a.shuffle
```

This will give you different results every time.